# ListView Alternate Row Color in Xamarin

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin app, I'm using `foreach` loop to get the **name** and **value** of available credentials and then Print it on screen using `ListView`.

e.g.

Name 1 
Value 1

Name 2 
Value 2

It is working fine. What I want now is to change the style of **Name** (`_attributes.Add(item.Name.ToString());`).

e.g.

**Name 1** 
Value

**Name 2** 
Value

**View.xml**

```
<ListView
    SeparatorVisibility="None"
    BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Attributes}"
    HasUnevenRows="true">

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Label
                    Text="{Binding .}" 
                    TextColor="#000000"
                    FontSize="18"
                    Padding="10" >
                </Label>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
foreach (var item in _credential.CredentialAttributesValues)
{
    _attributes.Add(item.Name.ToString());
    _attributes.Add(item.Value.ToString());
}

private ObservableCollection<string> _attributes = new ObservableCollection<string>();
public ObservableCollection<string> Attributes
{
    get
    {
        return _attributes;
    }
    set
    {
        this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _attributes, value);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
<ViewCell>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label
        Text="{Binding Name}" 
        TextColor="#000000"
        FontSize="18"
        Padding="10"
        Margin="10,0,0,0">
        </Label>

        <Label
        Text="{Binding Value}" 
        TextColor="#000000"
        FontSize="18"
        Padding="10"
        Margin="10,0,0,0">
        </Label>
    </StackLayout>
</ViewCell>
```

```
private ObservableCollection<CredentialPreviewAttribute> _attributes = new ObservableCollection<CredentialPreviewAttribute>();
public ObservableCollection<CredentialPreviewAttribute> Attributes
{
    get
    {
        return _attributes;
    }
    set
    {
        this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _attributes, value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have used string datatype it is difficult to understand which string in collection will be name, however if you want to give style according to you index you can follow below link:

https://blog.verslu.is/stackoverflow-answers/alternate-row-color-listview/

or

assuming you have Model named Credential

```
public class Credential
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

and in your ViewModel

```
private ObservableCollection<Credential> _attributes = new ObservableCollection<Credential>();
public ObservableCollection<Credential> Attributes
{
   get
   {
       return _attributes;
   }    
   set
   {
       this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _attributes, value);
   }
}
```

and in .xaml

```
<ListView
    SeparatorVisibility="None"
    BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Attributes}"
    HasUnevenRows="true">

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label
                        Text="{Binding Name}" 
                        TextColor="#000000"
                        Style="[Whatever you want...]"
                        FontSize="18"
                        Padding="10" >
                    </Label>
                    <Label
                        Text="{Binding Value}" 
                        TextColor="#000000"
                        FontSize="18"
                        Padding="10" >
                    </Label>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

You can also use single label to achieve the requested view requirement in your question.

```
<Label>
   <Label.FormattedText>
      <FormattedString>
         <Span Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="Black" />
         <Span Text="&#10;" />
         <Span Text="{Binding Value}" TextColor="Gray" />
      </FormattedString>
   </Label.FormattedText>
</Label>
```

Comment: this is the name `_attributes.Add(item.Name.ToString());` ... ???

Comment: can't open this link. can u?

Comment: yes, looking at it anyone can get that but, in your ViewModel you have created collection of string datatype. I suggest you to create the collection of object(type of item) in your ViewModel then it will be easily identified which is your name and which is value.

Comment: thanks for ur response, I'm using `foreach` and adding `name` and `value`... model can't replace it..

Comment: `item.Name.ToString()` & `item.Value.ToString()` says, **cannot convert from 'string' to 'Mobile.App.Credentials..............**

Comment: What r u adding in collection?show me your syntax.

Comment: In your viewmodel you still have observableCollection of string, make it collection of credentialpreviewattribute class and add entire item in collection instead of item.name or item.value and also update your view as I have shown in my example u will get it.

Comment: I updated the code as u said.. now, nothing shows up.. I update the code above as u told me to.. have a look.. is it right? and I also remove the `_attributes.Add(item.Name.ToString());` and `_attributes.Add(item.Value.ToString());`

Comment: _attributes.Add(item) add item like this.

Answer (score 1):

**View.xml**

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <Label
                Text="{Binding .}" 
                TextColor="#000000"
                Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"
                FontSize="18"
                Padding="10" >
            </Label>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

**Style.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="NameProject.Style.GeneralStyle">

<Style TargetType="Label" x:Key="LabelStyle1">
    <Setter Property="Padding">
        <Setter.Value>
            <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="Thickness" Phone="10" Tablet="50"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="FontSize">
        <Setter.Value>
            <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Phone="18" Tablet="24"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="red"/>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="Label" x:Key="LabelStyle2">
    <Setter Property="Padding">
        <Setter.Value>
            <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="Thickness" Phone="12" Tablet="50"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="FontSize">
        <Setter.Value>
            <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Phone="20" Tablet="24"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Blue"/>
</Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

**Style.cs**

```
public static General SharedInstance { get; } = new General();
```

**App.cs**

```
dictionary.MergedDictionaries.Add(Style.General.SharedInstance);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.